# Javascript - Fastest search for a word in array of string (not full match also)

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, search

I am coding search on a webpage which searchs all files, which the webpage consists of.
I iterate through every file and save all words to array of strings.
For example: `var array = ["these","are","some","random","words","on","a","webpage"]`

The search engine works this way: e.g. user type `"s"` and if any word from array contains this letter, the word is displayed as a result. In this case the results would be: `"these", "some", "words"`

The problem is that I have like 30 files in which I search and in each file there is on average 500 words so the search is slow.

1. letter search (e.g. "s") ~ 4 seconds
2. letter search (e.g. "se") ~ 2.1 seconds
3. letter search (e.g. "sea") ~ 1.9 seconds
4. letter search (e.g. "sear") ~ 1.7 seconds...

I iterate through the `array` with for-cycle and I think that is the biggest problem. So what is the fastest way to find if searched word is in array of strings and compare also not full matches?

EDIT:

On the webpage it looks like this e.g.:
Searched word: "sear"
Results:
**Intro** (name of page; clickable url link)
...you can search in this page... (sentence with words around the searched word)

Code explanation:

- iterating through files
- remove html characters and other special characters and save words from file to array of strings
- compare words from file with words which user search for
- save sentence with the searched word to a `sentence` variable
- save `sentence` to an object (this object is later iterated in .html file and the sentences are displayed at webpage)

words typed by user which are going to be searched are in variable `words`

Here is my code.

```js
var searchIndexPromise;
var searchAppModule = angular.module("searchApp", []);

searchAppModule.run(function($rootScope, $http){
    var globalSearch = $rootScope.globalSearch = {
        query: "",
        results: [],
        open: function(){
            window.location.href = "#!/51_00_Search";
            globalSearch.search(globalSearch.query);
        },
        search: function(find) {            
            if(!searchIndexPromise) searchIndexPromise = $http.get("searchIndex.json").then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            });

            console.log("searching", find);
            searchIndexPromise.then(function(searchIndex){
                var temp = [];
                globalSearch.results = [];
                var words = find.split(' ');
                if (words < 1) {
                    return;
                }
                for (var key in searchIndex) {
                    for (var option in searchIndex[key]) {
                        for(var i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
                            if (key.includes(words[i].toLowerCase())) {
                                var name = searchIndex[key][option].name;
                                var page = searchIndex[key][option].page;
                                var word = words[i];
                                var count = 0;
                                for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                                    if (temp[j].name == name && temp[j].word == word) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    count++;
                                }
                                if (count == temp.length) {
                                    temp.push({ name : name, page : page, word : word });
                                }                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (words.length < 2) {
                    globalSearch.results = temp;
                }
                else {                
                    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                        var count = 0;
                        var compare = temp[i];                    
                        for (var j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                            if (compare.name == temp[j].name) {
                                if (globalSearch.results.indexOf(temp[j]) == -1) {
                                    count++;
                                }                            
                            }
                        }
                        if (count == words.length) {
                            globalSearch.results.push(temp[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //sentences
                const pagesLoad = require("./pages.js");
                globalSearch.pages = [];
                for (var result in globalSearch.results) {
                    var page = globalSearch.results[result].page.substring(3);
                    if ((page + ".html" in pagesLoad)) {
                        var nameOfPage = page + ".html";
                    }
                    if ((page + ".md" in pagesLoad)) {
                        var nameOfPage = page + ".md";
                    }
                    var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)|\n|\#|\(|\)|\*|\-|[^\w\s!?]|\n| +(?= )/ig, data = pagesLoad[nameOfPage].src.replace(regex, " ");
                    var string = data.split(" ");
                    string = string.filter(Boolean);
                    let lowerString = string.map((item) => {
                        return item.toLowerCase();
                    });
                    //this part is slowing down the search
                    for (var i = 0; i < lowerString.length; i++) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
                            if (lowerString[i].includes(words[j].toLowerCase())) {
                                var sentence = "...";
                                for (var k = i - 6; k < i + 6; k++) {
                                    if (lowerString[k] == null) {
                                        continue;
                                    }
                                    sentence = sentence + string[k] + " ";
                                }
                                sentence = sentence.slice(0, -1);
                                sentence += "...";
                                globalSearch.pages.push({page: globalSearch.results[result].page, sentence: sentence});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you use some kind of JS/node database? Then your words will be indexed properly and will be fast.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't. I was rather thinking about some pattern search or binary search... but I am not an expert on frontend so could you please explain to me that JS/node database thing ?:)

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: I have edited my question, hope you can understand it:)
P.S. that's not my whole code but the substantial part of it

Comment: Can you also include code that searches for user content? Also, I hope you cache parsed result and not re-execute on every user visit?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "user content". No, I don't catch results.. after user type some letter or word, the search.js file is opened and all results are searched from beginning

Comment: So show `search.js`

Comment: I have edited my question again... also I have uploaded the whole search.js file